# Не могу обратиться к API из контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть сайт с заметками, в котором имеется возможность создавать заметки. После ввода заметки, я обращаюсь к API и передаю модель заметки для того, чтобы внести ее в БД. Но это не работает, при обращение оно возвращает код 400 и даже не входит в контроллер API. Хотя точно такой же код в другом контроллере созданный для проверки работает и также работает GET обращение. Все пути и имена верны.
Код контроллера приложения

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNote(string? NoteText, string? NoteTitle)
{
    //Заглушка
    NoteViewModel viewModel = new NoteViewModel()
    {
        ClientId = 1,
        NoteTypeId = 1,
        NoteText = NoteText,
        EditDate = DateTime.Now,
        NoteTitle = NoteTitle
    };
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(data.ToLower(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(baseAddres + "/DailyNotes/CreateNote", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Notes", new { clientId = 1});
    }
    return View();
}
```

Код контроллера API

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Note>> CreateNote(NoteViewModel note)
{
    try
    {
        if (note == null)
            return BadRequest("Cant be Null");
        await _dailyNotesRepository.CreateNote(note);
        return Ok(note);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение на анг StackOverflow

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(baseAddres + "/DailyNotes/CreateNote", new NoteViewModel()
        {
            ClientId = 1,
            NoteTypeId = 1,
            NoteText = NoteText,
            EditDate = DateTime.Now,
            NoteTitle = NoteTitle
        });
```